# Populating ComboBox from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to populate my **combobox** from **sql** but when i assign a value member to it, it gives me the following error

```
cannot explicitly convert int into string
```

Could you help me understand and correct my mistake?

```
 void Fillcombo()
    {
         string query_select = "SELECT * FROM department";
         DataTable dt = DataAccess.selectData(query_select);
         SqlDataReader dr = DataAccess.selectDataReader(query_select);
         while (dr.Read())
            {
                string dpt_name = dr.GetString(1);
                int dpt_id = (int)dr.GetValue(0);
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
                comboBox1.ValueMember = dpt_id; // error here
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = dpt_name;

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign name of column in `DataSource` (`DataTable`) to `ValueMenmber` and `DisplayMember` as string, and you don't need to use while loop, like this :

```
void Fillcombo()
{
    string query_select = "SELECT * FROM department";
    DataTable dt = DataAccess.selectData(query_select);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ColumnName_DepartmentID";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ColumnName_DepartmentName";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use while loop like answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write it in a string format:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "dpt_id";
```